# How do I stop a media query forcing inheritance of both "left" and "right" css property on a div?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a media query and corresponding CSS that sets up a toolset on the right side of the screen in the case for desktop users and on the bottom for mobile.  However, it overrides the CSS properties and assigns 0 to both "left" and "right".  What I am doing wrong?  Please see the screenshot from firebug below.

[image]

Here are my media tags:

```
 /* 
- Binds all layouts together with imports and mediaqueries.
*/

//@import "libs/reset.less";

@import "mediaqueries/global.less";
@import "mediaqueries/desktop.less";
@import "mediaqueries/mobile.less";



@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
.mqMobile; /* Use mix-in to make sure that the styles are expanded inside the     mediaquery */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.mqDesktop; /* Use mix-in to make sure that the styles are expanded inside the    mediaquery */
}
```

Comment: Where are your media query tags?  You need to encapsulate each #toolset in its own media query

Comment: Post actual code not a screenshot and create a simplified example of your problem on Jsfiddle.net

Comment: Well, `.mqMobile` and `.mqDesktop` aren't terribly helpful if we don't know which rules those mixins correspond to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the mobile media query, use `right: auto`. This should override the normal CSS, and switch the `right` property from `0` without actually specifying a specific value. For example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .mqMobile {
        left: 0;
        right: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to add media query in ur css file.

*This will target all*

```
    #toolset{
      float:left;
    }
```

*This will target mobile*

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

     #toolset{
        float:right;
     }

}
```

Refer to this:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/